# How to run the DbMigrator class library after deploying an ABP.IO project?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, abp

In abp.io template project (UI: Webassembly, Database: Entity Framework Core, Tiered: Not Tiered)
I need to publish the project to IIS. I know that I should publish just the .Host and the .Blazor.
But how I can run the DbMigrator to create the DB and seed the data?

I tried to publish the .Host but I got this error
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at this [article](https://blog.elmah.io/http-error-500-30-asp-net-core-app-failed-to-start-help/)

Answer (score 0):

For creating the database and tables

- Generate the migration file using the dotnet command:
  `dotnet ef migrations add "MIGRATION_NAME"` using the Visual Studio Developer terminal on the `EntityFrameworkCore` project
  **OR**
  The Package Manager Console command as : `Add-Migration "MIGRATION_NAME"`
- Check the new generated file in `EntityFrameworkCore` project, in `Migrations` repository
- Run the `DbMigrator` project as a startup project.

See also:

- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core-Migrations
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli